# Why vue-devtools does not show Vuex store?

Tags: nativescript-vue

Vue developer tools are connected properly but it does not show vuex store. Is it expected behavior or should devtools show vuex store in nativescript projects?
I am using [Groceries-vue](https://github.com/tralves/groceries-ns-vue) project to test vuex store and devtools.

[image: vuex]

Comment: did you solve this problem? I use Meteor.js and have got same problem. Any tip from github not working.

Comment: Vuex store displayment is not supported with nativescript-vue.